# Ruby hash value truthiness and symbols

Tags: ruby

Could somebody please explain why the variable named `foo` remains `true` in the code below, even though it's set to `false` when the method is called? And why the symbol version behaves as expected?

```
def test(options = {})
  foo = options[:foo] || true
  bar = options[:bar] || :true
  puts "foo is #{foo}, bar is #{bar}"
end

>> test(:foo => false, :bar => :false)
foo is true, bar is false
```

I've only tried this using Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Do you mean `true` not `:true` in the third line?

Comment: @Andrew No, I did mean `:true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
foo = options[:foo] || true
```

with `options[:foo]` being `false` could be rewritten as

```
foo = false || true
```

and that is clearly `true`.

The operator `||` can only be used as an "unless defined" operator when the first operator will take a false value (e.g. `nil`) when not defined. In your case `false` is a defined value, so you can't use `||` the way you do. Try rewriting it this way:

```
foo = options.fetch(:foo, true)
```

That will return the value of the `:foo` key, or `true` if it's not set.

Answer (score 2):

|| is OR.
What you are basically doing is assigning foo to false || true. OR returns true when at least one of the options is true, or false when they're both false.

The truth table of the OR gate is as follows:

```
INPUT1 | INPUT2 | OUTPUT
   0   |    0   |   0
   0   |    1   |   1
   1   |    0   |   1
   1   |    1   |   1
```